# How to access shapefile table in QGIS Modeler R scripts?

Tags: qgis, r, sextante

I need to develop .rsx scripts for QGIS 2.0.1 Modeler to do statistical elaborations on data tables of loaded vector layers.

In this case I am not interested in accessing shapefile geometries, I'd like R to read layer table as a dataframe.

Unfortunately the only way (I know) to read data from the table of a vector layer in .rsx scripts is to state:

```
##vector_layer=vector
```

And then use the following R code

```
vector_df=as.data.frame(vector_later)
```

The OGR library used to access vector layers in R is very slow for shapefiles with many features.

Is there any other method to make R read the data table of a loaded vector layer in QGIS without accessing geometries?

Something like read.dbf() {foreign library} ....

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you run a  .rsx  script ?

You must examine the `Rutils.py` script

It creates a temporary R script with the desired command (`/.qgis2/processing/processing_script.r`) and use the Python module `subprocess` to execute it

```
 command = "R CMD BATCH --vanilla " + RUtils.getRScriptFilename() + " "+ RUtils.getConsoleOutputFilename()
 proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
```

When you write

```
##vector_layer=vector
vector_df=as.data.frame(vector_later)
```

In the temporary script, it is

```
options("repos"="http://cran.at.r-project.org/")
tryCatch(find.package("rgdal"), error=function(e) install.packages("rgdal",     dependencies=TRUE))
tryCatch(find.package("raster"), error=function(e) install.packages("raster", dependencies=TRUE))
library("raster")
library("rgdal")
Layer = readOGR("directory",layer="vector_layer")
```

and the result is a Spatial Dataframe (look at [Things I Forget: Reading a Shapefile in R with readOGR](http://www.r-bloggers.com/things-i-forget-reading-a-shapefile-in-r-with-readogr/))

Therefore, it uses R with the [rgdal](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) package, by default, to read the original shapefile and not the ogr library of QGIS.

Thus, it is a problem of [rgdal](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) and even if you use other R packages, as for example:

```
##Point pattern analysis=group
##Layer=vector
library("maptools")
library("spatstat")
ppp=as(as(Layer, "SpatialPoints"),"ppp")
```

the resulting temporary file still use rgdal to read the shapefile:

```
options("repos"="http://cran.at.r-project.org/")
tryCatch(find.package("maptools"), error=function(e) install.packages("maptools", dependencies=TRUE))
tryCatch(find.package("spatstat"), error=function(e) install.packages("spatstat", dependencies=TRUE))
tryCatch(find.package("rgdal"), error=function(e) install.packages("rgdal", dependencies=TRUE))
tryCatch(find.package("raster"), error=function(e) install.packages("raster", dependencies=TRUE))
library("raster")
library("rgdal")
Layer = readOGR("directory",layer="layer")
```

In conclusion,If you are not satisfied, use R directly or Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can save the attributes table of your shapefile as a .csv table (Save as -> Choose Format .csv) and then make a Qgis-R script that accepts a table as input:

```
##Folder= folder
##Table=table
setwd(Folder)
Table*2->table_out
write.table(table_out,"table_out.csv",row.names=F)
```

Note that Qgis-R can not create "table" output (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8919), so as a workaround you need the make the script export the table to a user defined output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check dbfpy at http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/ it's made specific for DBF files. An alternative is OGR or PyShp.

Comment: I think mic_cord wanted a solution in R not python